# android- architecture component return nothing on android

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, android-architecture-components, android-viewmodel

I'm new in  architecture component and kotlin. 
I've written and app that works fine one android pre orio but it returns nothing on android orio and above .

these are my codes, this is my code for retrofit connection

```
object ApiConnection {
val BaseUrl ="http://site.ir/"
val client: Retrofit
    get() {
        val gson = GsonBuilder()
            .setLenient()
            .create()

        ///for Logging
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        val client = OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(interceptor).build()


        var retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
            .client(client)
            .build()
        return retrofit
    }
```

}

this is my code for activity :

```
 lateinit var rc_peyk:RecyclerView;
lateinit var peykViewModel:PeykHistoryViewModel
lateinit var peykHistAdapter: PeykHistoryAdapter

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.peyk_history)

    declare();

    peykViewModel= ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(PeykHistoryViewModel::class.java)
    peykViewModel.getPeyks(Func.getUid(this)).observe(this
            , Observer<MutableList<Peyk_item>>{
        if(it==null){
            MyToast.makeText(this@PeykHistory, "null 1");
        }
        if(it!=null && it.size==0){
            MyToast.makeText(this@PeykHistory, "size 0");
        }
        if(it!=null && it.size>0){
            peykHistAdapter= PeykHistoryAdapter(this@PeykHistory,it)
            rc_peyk.adapter=peykHistAdapter
        }
    })

    actionbar()
}
 private fun declare() {
        rc_peyk=findViewById(R.id.rc_peyk_history)
        rc_peyk.layoutManager=LinearLayoutManager(this)
    }
```

this is the code view viewModel :

```
class PeykHistoryViewModel(application:Application):AndroidViewModel(application){
private val peykRepository:PeykHistoryRepository= PeykHistoryRepository()
private lateinit var peykHistory:MutableLiveData<MutableList<Peyk_item>>

fun getPeyks(uid:String):MutableLiveData<MutableList<Peyk_item>>{
    if(!::peykHistory.isInitialized){
        peykHistory=peykRepository.getPeyks(uid)
    }
    return peykHistory
}
```

this is the code for repository :

```
class PeykHistoryRepository {
private lateinit var getPeykHistory: getPeykHistoryApi
private lateinit var peykList: MutableLiveData<MutableList<Peyk_item>>

fun getPeyks(uid: String): MutableLiveData<MutableList<Peyk_item>> {
    if (!::peykList.isInitialized) {
        peykList = MutableLiveData()
    }
    getPeykHistory = ApiConnection.client.create(getPeykHistoryApi::class.java)
    getPeykHistory.getPeykHistory(uid)
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe({ result ->
                if(result.peyks!=null){
                    peykList+=result.peyks
                }else{
                    Log.v("this","nothing");
                }
            }, { error ->
                Log.v("this",error.localizedMessage.toString())
            })

    return peykList;
}

operator fun <T> MutableLiveData<MutableList<T>>.plusAssign(values: List<T>) {
    val value = this.value ?: arrayListOf()
    value.addAll(values)
    this.value = value
}
```

there is no error and the api is fine and return the correct json .

could you help me ? I've tried too many things but doesn't help me

Comment: What is `declare()`? Is there ever a `LinearLayoutManager` set to the `RecyclerView`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce  yes, I've declared my recyelview and layoutmanager , as I said it shows perfectly on android pre orio

Comment: @EpicPandaForce I just attached my declare function , could you check it out ?

Comment: Can you post your Adapter class?